# VirtualBox - Bridged machines can't access Host, and machines can't see each other

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have two VMs, windows 10 and kali linux. Both of the machines are bridged with the IPs 192.168.1.103 and 192.168.1.120 respectively.
Both the machines can access 192.168.1.1 (ping and also the router HTTP server)

Both the machines can't see each other or the host (ping, or http)

Host can see both machines, host has the IP 192.168.1.111

I am not sure why the machines can't see each other or the host machine. I disabled all the firewall rules and still didn't work!

Comment: Sometimes, changing the mode from bridged to NAT fixes the problem, even when switching back. Are you using static IPs? What OS for the host? It would help to [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1713390/edit) your post and add the outputs of ipconfig/ifconfig on host and guests.

Comment: Thanks, I tried switching to NAT then back to bridge still didn't work. After updating virtualbox to latest version everything worked as expected.

Comment: You should not have asked the question without first updating your software.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked fine after updating virtualbox to latest version